# Is it worth manually setting Hikari's autoCommit to false in a MS SQL DB connection with Exposed framework in Kotlin?

Tags: database, hikaricp, kotlin-exposed

I am currently working on an application that has to connect to a MS SQL DB. It’s in Kotlin so I’m using the Exposed framework for all my transactions. I recently configured Hikari with this and just wanted to see the optimal settings for performance. I read through their docs and think I got everything except for the autoCommit setting. By default this is set to true - at least from their docs - I wanted to know if manually setting this value to false would be impactful in a meaningful way. I’ve done some testing and on average, with the autocommit set to false, my responses are ~100-200 Ms faster. But I’m not really sure if that’s worth much. I’d really like to see if anyone has encountered this since I haven’t seen any one talk about this specific instance.

I’ve tried both configurations. And I read that exposed also tries to set the value to false but then I get different response times - which again I’m not sure if they are  negligible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.